# How can I get more than one value from the Redux store in a single statement?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have this code:

```
const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.userReducer);
const { other } = useSelector((state) => state.otherReducer);
```

How could I get in one line those two (or more) values from the store?

```
const { user, other } = useSelector((state) => ?);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const { user, other } = useSelector((state) => ({ 
  user: state.userReducer,
  other: state.otherReducer
}))
```

If you use lodash:

```
import { pick, isEqual } from 'lodash-es';

const { userReducer, otherReducer } = useSelector(
  (state) => pick(state, ['userReducer', 'otherReducer']), 
  isEqual
)
```

The second param (`isEqual`) is aimed at resolving the potential performance issue mentioned by @NicholasTower (and is equivalent to `react-redux`'s `shallowEqual`).
Without a shallow object equality function, the component will re-render every time ***any*** mutation is committed to that store, regardless of key.

Comment: Thanks, I pick this one as the correct because was the first one

Answer (score 2):

The naive way to do it on one line would be to write a function that grabs the parts of state you care about, and constructs an object with those properties:

```
const { user, other } = useSelector((state) => {
  return { user: state.userReducer, other: state.otherReducer };
});
```

However, this will immediately cause a performance problem. Every time the selector runs, it creates a brand new object. And even if `user` and `other` havn't changed, the outer object *has* changed, so your component is forced to rerender. In other words, your component will rerender every time any action is dispatched anywhere in the app.

To fix this, `useSelector` allows you to provide an additional function which defines whether two values are equal or not. You can then implement a function to check if the stuff you care about has changed:

```
const { user, other } = useSelector((state) => {
  return { user: state.userReducer, other: state.otherReducer };
}, (a, b) => {
  return a.user === b.user && a.other === b.other
});
```

react-redux comes with a shallow comparison function which may be useful for this purpose if you prefer:

```
import { useSelector, shallowEqual } from 'react-redux';
// ...

const { user, other } = useSelector((state) => {
  return { user: state.userReducer, other: state.otherReducer };
}, shallowEqual);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment to my poor solution, it will help me in a lot of scenarios that I'm getting a problem with that

Comment: `And even if user and other havn't changed` so if I just deconstruct one reducer, will happen the same? so always will happen? In that case I'll had to to that in many useSelectors around the app, even if it's like: `const { userReducer } = useSelector((state) => state);`

Comment: The destructuring doesn't have any effect on whether the component renders. What matters is what's returned by the selector. If you use the selector `(state) => state`, then it will check if the previous state equals the new state, and rerender if it changed. If you use the selector `(state) => state.userReducer`, it will check if the previous state's `.userReducer` is the same as the new state's `.userReducer`.

Comment: I see, so the big problem is returning always the complete `state`

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest using array instead of objects to avoid repeating keys

```js
const [user, other] = useSelector(state => [state.userReducer, state.otherReducer])
```

Answer (score 0):

Meh, it was:

```
  const { userReducer: { user }, otherReducer: { other } } = useSelector((state) => state);
```

Comment: Be aware that this will rerender any time any part of the state changes, even if that change isn't in .userReducer or .otherReducer.